# Can we say that the curl of $E$ for an electromagnetic wave is zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

[here](http://kirkmcd.princeton.edu/examples/volt.pdf) (page 11) the following statement is written about the curl of the electric field in a TEM wave on a transmission line (⊥ indicates the component on the plane orthogonal to the propagation axis z):

> Since $B_z = 0$, Faraday’s law tells us that,
>
> $0 = −\frac{∂B_z}{∂t} = (∇ × E)_z = ∇_⊥ × E_⊥ e^{j(ωt−kz)}
> , $
>
> where $∇_⊥ = (∂/∂x, ∂/∂y)$. Hence, the 2-dimensional, time-independent
> field $E_⊥$ has zero curl, and so can be deduced from a (static)
> 2-dimensional scalar potential $V_⊥$ according to,
>
> $E_⊥ = −∇_⊥V_⊥$.

Can we apply the same logic on an ordinary (TEM) electromagnetic wave? It seems quite strange to me, because zero curl of E means something like an electrostatic situation, and so how can the wave propagate in such a situation? But at the same time, I cannot find the mistake in such a proof if applied to an ordinary electromagnetic wave.

My question **in other words**: is it possible to say that $E$ may be expressed as the **transverse (2D) curl** of an electric potential $V$ in an electromagnetic wave?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are seeing the problem wrong, the curl of E its not zero, the text, just say that the $z$ component of $\nabla\times \vec{E}$ is zero that means that there is not magnetic field on the direction of the conductor but there exist magnetif field in other dimesions,  for example the $y$ component of  $\nabla\times \vec{E}$ is $\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial z}\neq 0$. If $\nabla\times E=0$  then is true that we have and static field, you can see this becase $\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}=0$ that means there is not variation of the magnetic fiel in the time

Comment: So, the text says that the transverse curl of $E$ is zero, not the entire curl, correct? If the logic is this, can we say that the transverse field of a TEM wave has zero transverse curl (and so is equal to -∇V)?

Comment: Exactly, not the entiere curl, if the curl is zero there is not electric wave, the text i think try to tell that so there is not electric field by the wave in the z direction, but if exist must be static, and that is the case becase we are in a conductor, so it carrie a current and there must be a electric field that is $\nabla V_{\perp}$ but is not for the wave is for the current of the conductor

Comment: Note you can have an electrostatic wave that satisfies $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = 0$ that has fluctuation (i.e., time-varying) electric fields.  The only thing this says in that circumstance is that the wave vector is parallel to the fluctuating electric fields.